# SVG polygon to fill svg parent

Tags: html, svg, polygon

I have an svg polygon and I am trying to get the polygon to fill to the size of the svg container. Changing the height and width attributes scales the polygon as expected however I do not want any of the whitespace between the polygon and svg. Is there a way to achieve this without having to re-do the points?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 20 20" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <title>2</title>
    <g id="2" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <polygon id="Rectangle" fill="#000000" points="6 4 14 4 14 12.6416575 10 16 6 12.6416575"></polygon>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could adjust the viewBox instead e.g.

```html
<svg width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="6 4 8 12" preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="background-color:red">
    <title>2</title>
    <g id="2" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <polygon id="Rectangle" fill="#000000" points="6 4 14 4 14 12.6416575 10 16 6 12.6416575"></polygon>
    </g>
</svg>
```